# RSpec - Rerun failed tests that are also tagged?

Tags: ruby, rspec

We have written a large number of selenium UI tests that very occasionally fail due to dumb reasons like a web server being too slow.  Additionally, we make heavy use of rspec tags to only run the tests that we want to run.   We want to retry ONLY the tests that are tagged with something AND that have previously failed.  In the following example, running `rspec --tag all --only_failures` runs the last two tests, when I only want it to run the 2nd test.

spec_helper.rb

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.example_status_persistence_file_path = "RunResults.txt"
end
```

test_spec.rb

```
require 'rspec'
require 'spec_helper'
require './test'

RSpec.describe Test do
    it "should pass", :all, :one do
        expect(1).to eql(1)
    end

    it "should fail", :all, :two do
        expect(1).to eql(2)
    end

    it "should fail", :three do
        expect(1).to eql(2)
    end
end
```

RunResults.txt

```
example_id               | status | run_time        |
------------------------ | ------ | --------------- |
./spec/test_spec.rb[1:1] | passed | 0.00055 seconds |
./spec/test_spec.rb[1:2] | failed | 0.01796 seconds |
./spec/test_spec.rb[1:3] | failed | 0.00017 seconds |
```

RSpec

```
$ rspec --tag all --only_failures
Run options: include {:all=>true, :last_run_status=>"failed"}
.FF

Failures:

  1) Test should fail
     Failure/Error: expect(1).to eql(2)
     
       expected: 2
            got: 1
     
       (compared using eql?)
     # ./spec/test_spec.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Test should fail
     Failure/Error: expect(1).to eql(2)
     
       expected: 2
            got: 1
     
       (compared using eql?)
     # ./spec/test_spec.rb:15:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.01949 seconds (files took 0.24733 seconds to load)
3 examples, 2 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/test_spec.rb:10 # Test should fail
rspec ./spec/test_spec.rb:14 # Test should fail
```